# as3 export as pdf?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a drawing application that exports images to 150dpi jpg file currently. When these are printed they are giving the best results and the printer asked if I could provide the files in a pdf.

Is this possible directly from flash?

If I do use a php script to convert the jpg to a pdf, will that be the same quality?

Other than pdf, what other image formats could I use that might produce better results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/), it's ActionScript3 PDF library. Here is nice [tutorials](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/?page_id=5) page

You should be able to preserve picture quality when converting to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is scale the displayobject in flash before taking a snapshot as a Bitmap and converting to a png using pngencoder... this allows us to print at a much higher dpi and have it come out the same size (i.e. for 300dpi scale your image by 2.

Comment: I have tried converting to png and the encode time takes forever with large images.